# Javascript timer not working when php gives it a date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, date, timer

Okay since I am not to familiar with javascript I had php spit out a date if it matches certain criteria. I stored the date in a session variable so that it wouldnt be lost on a refresh, as I know php variables lose their value when the page is refreshed. I declared a variable with a stactic date to see if the date is being fed to the javascript timer. It is not reaching the timer. I tested with an alert to see if it was being fed to javascript and sure enough it is. No errors in the console. I thought maybe it was the fact that javascript counts dates 0-11 instead of 1-12 like php does, and I accounted for that and no change. All I see is the text that gets rendered when timer is done counting down.

Basically the date is not reaching this block:

```
window.onload=function(){
  var cdown = new CDown();

  cdown.add(new Date(CountDownDate), "countbox1");
};
```

I have no idea how to fix the javascript so that date does reach that block. I tried putting that static date in the block and still no change, but if I change CountDownDate to a static string then it works like a charm.

Comment: No one will look through all of these code for you. Please distill your program to ideally 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: Yeah in the works of doing that now.

Comment: So on my own on this one I guess

Answer (score 0):

Wow the fix was sooo simple....

I looked up date object on w3schools and tested my format and it didnt work. I was using this format for dates:

yyyy,mm,dd,hh,mm,ss

I know the above format is in fact valid, because I have seen it used in tutorials before, but when I used the following format it worked like a charm:

yyyy mm dd hh:mm:ss

The one thing I dont get is that I wasnt getting no errors in the console when I used the first format. I guess the first format doesnt work when it is in a variable.